# Securing Logstash to Logstash in different domains

Tags: ssl, logstash, tls1.3

I have a requirement for Logstash1 to send data to Logstash2 that are in 2 different environments. There will be network routing between each environment on ip level. But no DNS between each logstash. As such their FQDN's will not resolve as these are locally managed.

How can I setup secure encryption between the 2 servers? As I presume Logstash2 will not be able to verify Logstash1 due to FQDN's not resolving.

Thanks